# Testing iframe in Angular / Karma/Jasmine returns cross site scripting error

Tags: angular, iframe, jasmine, karma-runner

I have an Angular(10) component with html with an iframe.
Whatever I do with sanitizing the URL (`bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl`) I get a cross site scripting error:

> Error: unsafe value used in a resource URL context (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)

Below is the important parts of my code.

Beside the code below I have tried hard coding empty string, valid html, null, # and whatnot.
I have tried manipulating my mocked DomSanitizer; including turning it off.
I have verified my mock is called.

Right now I guess it is Karma that uses an iframe and then my code uses another/inner iframe and somewhere karma's setup does not allow for anything in my iframe.

(The only way I get Angular to not complain about the xss the iframe src/URL is to hard code it in the template.)

---

Template:

```
<iframe id="inlineFrameExample" [src]="embeddedLink">
</iframe>
```

.ts:

```
private url: string // Set elsewhere.

constructor(
  private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
) { }

public get embeddedLink(): SafeResourceUrl {
  return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.url);
}
```

.ts.spec:

```
...
providers: [
  {
    provide: DomSanitizer,
    useValue: {
      bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl: (val: string) => val,
    },
  },
...
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work just fine, imported it differently with a module containing everything needed.

Note: Working [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-unit-test-iframe-example?file=src/app/app.component.spec.ts).

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";

@NgModule({
  imports: [],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl } from "@angular/platform-browser";

@Component({
  selector: "myapp",
  templateUrl: "app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  private url: string = "https://www.testUrl.com/";

  constructor(public sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  public get embeddedLink(): SafeResourceUrl {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.url);
  }
```

}

**app.component.spec.ts**

```
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { AppModule } from "./app.module";

describe("iFrame tests", () => {
  let comp: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule],
      providers: [],
      declarations: []
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    comp = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it("should exist", () => {
    expect(comp).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```